# A process serving application pool 'App pool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool, windows-server, recycle

I have asp.net web forms application. I deployed program to IIS server and program is working well but all of users' InProc session often die at same time.
I know that appliaction pool often is recycle. I instaled **DebugDiagx64** program and add log this application pool. Result is that

```
Some exception details were omitted due to the following reasons
        The maximum number of stacks (MAX_CLR_EXCEPTION_STACKS_PER_EXCEPTION_TYPE = 10) for this CLR exception type have been collected: 'NOT_FOUND'
        The maximum number of stacks (MAX_CLR_EXCEPTION_STACKS_PER_EXCEPTION_TYPE = 10) for this CLR exception type have been collected: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'
        The maximum number of stacks (MAX_CLR_EXCEPTION_STACKS_PER_EXCEPTION_TYPE = 10) for this CLR exception type have been collected: 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'
        The maximum number of stacks (MAX_CLR_EXCEPTION_STACKS_PER_EXCEPTION_TYPE = 10) for this CLR exception type have been collected: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultReason'
        The maximum number of stacks (MAX_CLR_EXCEPTION_STACKS_PER_EXCEPTION_TYPE = 10) for this CLR exception type have been collected: 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext'
        The maximum number of stacks (MAX_CLR_EXCEPTION_STACKS_PER_EXCEPTION_TYPE = 10) for this CLR exception type have been collected: 'System.NullReferenceException'
        The maximum number of total stacks (MAX_CLR_EXCEPTION_STACKS_TOTAL = 100) for all CLR exception types have been collected)
        The maximum number of stacks (MAX_CLR_EXCEPTION_STACKS_PER_EXCEPTION_TYPE = 10) for this CLR exception type have been collected: 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. I am using UDT type and Odac version sometimes throw exception and app pool is recycled. I don't use udt type and problem is solved.