# IIS7 Server Application Pool suffered a fatal error

Tags: visual-studio, iis

After following the steps for [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204444/iis7-a-process-serving-application-pool-yyyyy-suffered-a-fatal-communication) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221114/a-process-serving-application-pool-app-pool-suffered-a-fatal-communication-err) and doing a lot of own research regarding the error I can not find a valid solution to this error.

When this error occurs the following image shows on the server itself as well:

[image: Image Error]

I have installed a debugging tool and ran it but the information given does not make any sense to me as a software developer. If anybody has any other solutions regarding this error it will be appreciated.

Comment: If you know enough about assembly language and C/C++, you won't say “the information given does not make any sense”. If possible, open a support case via http://support.microsof.com and consult Microsoft support.

Comment: Hi @LexLi. I will try and contact them but you are correct with the above comment I do not have enough knowledge regarding C/C++. Thank you